# Как организовать работу с проектом под старую ОС?

Tags: virtualbox, ос

На новой работе дали модернизировать проект на C++ (в том числе Qt 4) под старую ОС (Debian 6).

Дали виртуальную машину, но на такую ОС нет нормальной IDE, нет плюшек в виде современных пакетов с которыми удобнее работать.

Как разработку ведут в таких случаях?

Есть ли такие инструменты, которые бы позволяли работать с кодом из под современной ОС, а запускать и дебажить можно было бы сразу в виртуальной?

Может ещё какие советы дадите. Как делают софт под специфичную ОС?

Comment: Зависит от языка и его инструментария. Например, в Делфе удаленная отладка вполне себе работает. Поробуйте добавить в вопрос больше подробностей и деталей.

Comment: поправил текст, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В vscode позволяет работать с кодом, который находится на удалённой машине через [специальное расширение](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack).

Однако оно не работает со старой ОС. Поэтому я написал скрипты, которые реализуют тот же функционал.

[Скрипты доступны на github](https://github.com/rahmaevao/remote_develop).

Скрипты монтируют по SSH директорию с проектом, и отправляют команды сборки  и отладки в удаленную машину.

Сама виртуальная машина работает в тихом режиме. А запуск приложения происходит через технологию SSH forwarding.

Comment: У вас ссылки дублируются. Та, которая на GH, отсутствует.